# YOLOv4 darknet weights

Tags: object-detection, yolo, drive, yolov4

So I am training YOLOv4 using this command

```
!darknet/darknet detector train darknet/data/obj.data darknet/cfg/yolov4-obj.cfg yolov4.conv.137 -dont_show -map
```

and saving the weight files in my drive. Checking the drive I notice only best.weights and final.weights are being saved. How can I have the weights after every 1000 weights so I can choose the best later? and what is best.weights (I know that final.weights is updated after 100 iterations)
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Regarding saving weights, [this](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/issues/7308#issuecomment-770612710) may help you out.

`best.weights` are the weights that give the best mAP on the validation set that you have provided